# Is there any difference between past continuous + past simple and past perfect continuous + past simple?

Tags: difference, past-tense, past-continuous

Compare:

- We were watching a film when the power went out.
- We had been watching a film when the power went out.

Can you see any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Although from the moment the power went out, we could no longer be considered watching the film, we all understand how such events go.

The [past continuous](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+watching+a+film%2Chad+been+watching+a+film+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)
is clear, correct too, and preferred.
There's no difference in meaning.